# Using opa http.send with conftest

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego, conftest

I have a question about data importing and the execution of built-in opa function when using *conftest*. In the below code sample I have two modules `abc` and `main`. I've conveniently left out some of the set up for `abc` all that matters is that it's a working https call.

Working from the repl my code executes exactly as I intended, fetch data on the fly i.e. `available` and check if `stuff` is in that list. `opa run -b .`  then hitting `data.abc` executes the https call i.e. I can see packets leave my interface and a response body containing the list I need is pulled in. I then get the expected result from `deny`. The same thing happens when running `opa test . -v`.

However running `conftest verify -p .` or  `conftest test abc/main.json -p .` never executes `http.send` i.e. packets never leave my interface for the expected host.

I could use a static list rather than using the https call but I don't control when the list is updated. Is this expected/intended limitation of conftest? Can I execute these functions to build my data document and am I importing it correctly?

```
package abc

available = http.send(
  {
  "method": "get",
  "url": request.url,
  "headers": headers
  }
)
```

```
package main
import data.abc.available

deny[msg] {
    stuff := input.stuff
    not available.body[stuff]
    msg := sprintf("%v is not available", [stuff])
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in conftest to me. As far as I am aware there are no limitations that should prevent this. You can report the issue on the Conftest github: https://github.com/open-policy-agent/conftest/issues.

Comment: We created an issue for your post on the Conftest issue board: https://github.com/open-policy-agent/conftest/issues/424. I have not been able to reproduce your issue sadly. Maybe you can join on Github and we can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Hey, that's fine I'll follow up there with a better example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feex. https://gist.github.com/b0bu/67d60fc0dbc5a9ae36406188117dfb36

The issue was `import data.token as auth`

`auth` was undefined, by extension subscirptionid was never populated. This was working in `opa run -b .` because of a slight difference in how the data document is structured. `data.token.stuff` was a thing which translated to `data.stuff` in conftest.